# Junit5 coverage for Assert Throws

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, jacoco

How to cover the method call inside assertThrows in the code coverage using JUnit 5 and spring boot?

out of all my code only this piece is not covered. Want to cover this as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you tracking code coverage on your tests? Isn't that an inception test?

Comment: Code coverage by default scans all the code and shows the percentage. Just thought to cover this as well. Just a POC. But, expecting as good to know.

Comment: I don't recall JaCoCo doing that by default, but I might be wrong. Nevertheless, does the concept of tracking code coverage on your Test make sense to you?

Comment: Updated the question with my implementation and the report. Jacoco covers the Test  as well. Excluding, test is not a problem. But, is it now way we can cover this piece?

Comment: Ok, so two things about that in my opinion. 1. It makes no sense to track coverage of your tests. In fact, how does JaCoCo computes that? And then again, does this concept make sense to you? 2. Do not focus too much on Code Coverage or aim for 100%. Long story short even if you have 100% Code Coverage it does not guarantee that there are 0 bugs (check this very detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3123841/16572295).

Comment: Yeah. I agree with your point. Thank you João Dias